# Symfony how to use annotation @Security

Tags: symfony

I cant find any clear posts on how to use the annotation @Security of symfony.
What are the parameters i can use? And most important, how can i secure a controller from guests and only accessible for users?

Currently i have

```
/**
 * 
 * @Route("/reseller/create/", name="app_reseller_create", methods={"POST", "GET"})
 * @IsGranted("ROLE_ADMIN")
     */
public function create(Request $request): Response
{
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### @IsGranted

If you only want to check if a user is logged in, you can use a special attribute instead of a role. For the full controller you must set it over the class definition.

```php
/**
 * @IsGranted("IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY")
 */
class MyClass {
```

There are some special attributes that can use everywhere you can use ROLE_.

- `IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY` is logged in.
- `IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED` is logged in or have an remembered cookie.
- `IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY` any user have this
- `IS_ANONYMOUS` only guests
- `IS_REMEMBERED` only users with the rmembered cookie
- `IS_IMPERSONATOR` only users that impersonating another user in the session.

The `IS_ANONYMOUS`, `IS_REMEMBERED` and `IS_IMPERSONATOR` attributes were introduced in Symfony 5.1.

#### @Security

The security annotation is more flexible as the IsGranted annotation and can use expressions.

Say you want a page, that only can be access if the user is an admin and have a specific token in his request.

- with `@IsGranted`

```php
/**
 * @IsGranted("ROLE_ADMIN", statusCode=404)
 */
 public function show(Request $request, Post $post) 
 {
     if (!$request->request->has('privatetoken') || 'mytoken' !== $request->request->get('privatetoken')) {
        return $this->createNotFoundException('not found');
     }

     // Show Post
 }
```

- with `@Security`

```php
/**
 * @Security("is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN') and request.get('privatetoken') == 'mytoken'", statusCode=404)
 */
 public function show(Post $post)
 {
     // Show Post
 }
```

With this, you must have an admin role and have an `privatetoken` parameter in your url like `mydomain.com/post/show/?privatetoken=mytoken` and you don't need the Request instance.

The expression has access to the following variables:

- `token`: The current security token;
- `user`: The current user object;
- `request`: The request instance;
- `roles`: The user roles;
- and all request attributes.

There are too many possibilities to post this all. but i think it shows the difference to @IsGranted.

[Symfony Docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/security.html)

Comment: Thanks for sharing! I will need a way for my API. I think the token will work for it. But i would love if you have a recommendation

Comment: if you build your api with api-platform, it's the same thing. Take a look at: https://api-platform.com/docs/core/security/